# Как сравнить две строки?

Tags: c#, сравнение

Есть две строки. Одну написал я, другую  скопировал с браузера. Я начал их сравнивать и удивился когда они оказались отличными.  Как видим различия в первой букве `c`. Как сравнить или привести эти слова к одному виде и сравнить их?

```
    var x1 = "сow";
    var x2 = "cow";

    byte[] x1a = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x1); // 63 111 119
    byte[] x2a = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x2); // 93 111 119

 if (x1== x2)
       {

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первой строке у вас русское «с». Поэтому они и не равны.

Код 63 получился потому, что русское «с» нельзя представить в кодировке ASCII, и оно заменилось на знак вопроса.

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы русское «с» считалось эквивалентным английскому «c», можно, например, перед сравнением заменить в строке кириллические буквы на аналогичные буквы латиницы.